# Access element within iframe that is inside jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

HTML is pretty simple, on my page I have

```
<div id="notificationDialog" title="View Notification"></div>
```

I dynamically load notifications based on the user viewing the page, and display them inside an iframe, which is inside a jQuery ui dialog. Basically,

```
function viewNotif(nid) {
  var wWidth       = jQuery(window).width();
  var dWidth       = wWidth * 0.5;
  var $notifIframe = jQuery('<iframe />', {
      name: 'myFrame',
      id:   'myFrame',
      src: "/modals/modal_notification.php?nid="+nid,
      width:"100%",
      height:"100%",
      align:"center",
      scrolling:"auto",
      frameborder:"0"
  }); 

  jQuery('#notificationDialog').html($notifIframe.clone());

  jQuery('#notificationDialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: auto,
      width: dWidth,
      modal: true
  });

  jQuery('#notificationDialog').dialog('open');
}
```

I am trying to access the height value of a div that is within the iframe inside the jQuery ui dialog, and have thus far been unable to do so. How would I get the height value of a div, id of the div is notification_container which is inside the iframe, inside notificationDialog?

EDIT - I should mention that the function is called in an onClick one the page, and passes the notification ID (nid) to display, to the function.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("iframe").contents().find("#selector");
```

It should be noted that this is only allowable if the iframe contents are accessed locally. Otherwise you'll get an access denied error.

Comment: This gives me this error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLIFrameElement> has no method 'contents'

Comment: The iframe is on the same server as the page, but in a different folder. Is that not 'local'?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in case anyone stumbles upon it, the line above should be as follows:

`$("iframe").contents().find("#selector");`

(i.e. without the [0])